# Update date column with current date where NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has a column `publication_date` with format `DATE` (not `TIMESTAMP`), some old records has it `NULL` so I want to update it with current date. In PhpMyAdmin I try to execute this query:

```
UPDATE videos SET publication_date = now() WHERE publication_date = NULL
```

but as result I get 0 rows modified. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.
>   To test for NULL, use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators

Try this:

```
UPDATE videos SET publication_date = now() WHERE publication_date IS NULL
```